Vite: my websocket server is not starting
I followed apollo's documentation to have a websocket server (needed for subscription). Since I was tired of manually restarting the server on new changes, I tried to port it to vite. So far it worked great (I can query the http points, have live reload etc)… except that the websocket server is not working. If I run:
npx diagnose-endpoint@1.1.0 --endpoint="ws://localhost:5173/graphql"

Then I get a weird error message after quite some time:
⚠  Failed to diagnose what went wrong. Here's the error:  Error: socket hang up
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:530:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:90:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
} socket hang up
Would you care to let us know about this? Please mailto:explorer-feedback@apollographql.com

and subscriptions fail to work. On the other hand, if I configure the websocket server to use a different port with:
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  //server: httpServer,
  port: 4000,
  //  path: '/subscriptions',
  path: '/graphql',
});

Then the above diagnose tool finds no issue (but I can't try as I can't find how to configure the ws endpoint in Apolo). Unfortunately, if I use the port 5173 it tells me the port is already in use (even if I disable hmr with server: {hmr: false} in the config).
The important part of my code is this I guess:
// Create an Express app and HTTP server; we will attach both the WebSocket
// server and the ApolloServer to this HTTP server.
export const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

// Create our WebSocket server using the HTTP server we just set up.
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  server: httpServer,
  path: '/graphql',
});
// Save the returned server's info so we can shutdown this server later
const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

// Set up ApolloServer.
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  plugins: […],
});

await server.start();
app.use('/graphql', cors<cors.CorsRequest>(), express.json(), expressMiddleware(server));

if (!process.env['VITE']) { // When running from `vite` no need to call `app.listen`
  httpServer.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
  });
}

I m using vite3-plugin-express.
The full code is in https://github.com/leo-colisson/livekouiz/tree/main/livekouiz-backend-apollo-vite , just run npm dev run to start it, and type the above diagnose-endpoint command, or go to http://localhost:5173/graphql, and do the request:
subscription Subscription {
  hello
}

